Struggling to get rid of blank bar space in my barplot geom
So I have this issue for my barplot where there is a blank bar space for one (out of two) of my facets called 'competitive' but this is because there is no data for its variable 'other.'
I need to find a way to remove the blank space in only that one facet but I've been struggling on that for a long time­
Below is what I have atm in my code chunk and the pic is what my barplot looks like right now.
Any help would be appreciated!
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mapping = aes(x = talent,y = mnAud,fill = talent)) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_jitter(data=ds,mapping=aes(x=talent,y=mnAud,colour=talent), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), alpha=0.5,show.legend=FALSE) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 5, 10)) +
    geom_col(show.legend=FALSE,colour="black",alpha=0.5, stat="identity", position =     position_dodge(width = 0.1)) +
    geom_errorbar(mapping = aes(ymin = mnAud-sderrAud,
                              ymax = mnAud+sderrAud), width=0.2) +
    facet_wrap(~level) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") +
    scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1") +
    labs(title = "Audience rating for each kind of talent",
       y = "Rating (higher=better)",
       x = "Talent")


I've tried things like position = dodge and filtering but I have been unsuccessful thus far.

Try scales = "free_x" in facet_wrap.

Thank you but unfortunately did not work :(

file:///var/folders/ps/yck34jdn3f951725m333g84r0000gn/T/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_screencaptureui_D97Isa/Screen%20Shot%202024-04-14%20at%2010.37.00%20pm.png
this is the original data i am using called df
file:///var/folders/ps/yck34jdn3f951725m333g84r0000gn/T/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_screencaptureui_k7aJtR/Screen%20Shot%202024-04-14%20at%2010.37.49%20pm.png
and this is the ds data @carl (sorry im not sure how to add the datas without filling the character limit)

Edit the question with the data, please. (Don't post data or code in comments and don't post data or code as images.)

Rui's suggestion works for me per below with some made-up data and simplified code.
It's better if you can provide a minimal reproducible example including your own sample data as it could be that something else is preventing scales = "free_x" from having the desired effect, e.g. your geom_jitter references data = ds but we can't see what's in that.
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~level, ~talent, ~mnAud,
  "competitive", "comedy", 3,
  "fun", "dancing", 2,
  "competitive", "instrument", 3,
  "fun", "magic", 2,
  # "competitive", "other", 3, # remove other in one facet
  "fun", "singing", 2,
  "fun", "comedy", 3,
  "competitive", "dancing", 2,
  "fun", "instrument", 3,
  "competitive", "magic", 2,
  "fun", "other", 3,
  "competitive", "singing", 2
)

# with the gap
df |> ggplot(aes(talent, mnAud, fill = talent)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(talent, mnAud, colour = talent), show.legend = F) +
  geom_col(show.legend = F) +
  geom_errorbar(mapping = aes(ymin = mnAud - 0.1, ymax = mnAud + 0.1), width = 0.2) +
  facet_wrap(~level)



# with scales = "free_x"
df |> ggplot(aes(talent, mnAud, fill = talent)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(talent, mnAud, colour = talent), show.legend = F) +
  geom_col(show.legend = F) +
  geom_errorbar(mapping = aes(ymin = mnAud - 0.1, ymax = mnAud + 0.1), width = 0.2) +
  facet_wrap(~level, scales = "free_x")


Created on 2024-04-14 with reprex v2.1.0
